# MVC6 Dropdownlist of Countries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use MVC6 Tag Helpers to create a dropdownlist of CountryCode and CountryName so that a user can select their country after registering. The relevant part of the view looks like this so far

```cs
<form asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="EditCountry" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]">
<div asp-validation-summary="ValidationSummary.ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<select asp-for="CountryCode" asp-items="@Model.Countries"></select>
```

The relevant part of the viewmodel looks like this

```cs
[Display(Name = "Country")]
public string CountryCode { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Country> Countries { get; set; }
```

A Country looks like this

```cs
public partial class Country
{
    [Key]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

The controller returns a list of countries to the viewmodel

```
var model = new IndexViewModel
{
    CountryCode = user.CountryCode,
    Countries =_customersContext.Countries.OrderBy(c=>c.CountryName),
};
return View(model);
```

but in the view `asp-items="@Model.Countries"` has a squiggly `Cannot convert Country to SelectListItem`

Also I cannot find how in the form to specify CountryCode as the property to return and CountryName as the property to display.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The way I make my dropdowns is somewhat similar except that in my ViewModel, my property is of type `SelectList` instead of an `IEnumerable<>`.

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller I get the data and convert it to an anonymous list with two properties “Id” and “Value”.

In turn, I create a new `SelectList()` passing in the anonymous list specifying what is the `dataValueField` and what is the `dataTextField`.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var countries = _customersContext.Countries.OrderBy(c => c.CountryName).Select(x => new { Id = x.Code, Value = x.Name });

    var model = new HomeViewModel();
    model.CountryList = new SelectList(countries, "Id", "Value");

    return View(model);
}
```

Finally, in the View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="CountryCode" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select asp-for="CountryCode" asp-items="@Model.CountryList"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyViewModel  //MODEL LAYER
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> EmployeesList { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult Contact1()  //CONTROLLER
        {

        MyViewModel N1 = new MyViewModel();
        List<Employee> N2 = new List<Employee>()
        {
            new Employee { Id=1,FullName="sivaragu" },
             new Employee { Id=2,FullName="siva" },
                  new Employee { Id=3,FullName="SENTHIL" }
        };

        ViewBag.MovieType = N2;
        return View();            
    }
```

CSHTML(MVC6)

```
<select  asp-for="CountryId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.MovieType,"Id","FullName") )">    
    </select>
```

Comment: <select  asp-for="CountryId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(@ViewBag.MovieType,"Id","FullName") )">

    </select>

Comment: THIS CSHTML  CODE

Answer (score 1):

I have proposed an alternative way of doing this by extending the `SelectTagHelper` with some more attributes that can make this type of development more convenient. The issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5584).

It is based on a class `SelectListDescriptor` that contain the list of items, the property to display the text and value field respectively. Then in the view one simple type

`<select asp-descriptor="@ViewBag.CountryDescriptor"><option value="">-- Choose country</option<</select>`.

The country descriptor is just `new SelectListDescriptor(nameof(Country.CountryCode), nameof(Country.CountryName), countries)`. This avoid magic strings by utilizing the power of the `nameof-operator