# Bind foreign key data in dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my `MVC` application how can bind the `foreign key/relational` data in `dropdownlist` for the following scenario.

While showing particular course details, ALL course category should get filled and CourseCategoryID of the course should set to selected

I have created `model` like follow, but dropdown is filled only with the ONE value and not the entire list of course category ?

```
public partial class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int CourseCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CourseDesciption { get; set; }
    public string CourseTitle { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CourseCategoryID")]
    public virtual CourseCategory CourseCategory { get; set; }
}
public partial class CourseCategory
{
    public CourseCategory()
    {
        Course = new HashSet<Course>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int CourseCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CourseCategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Course { get; set; }

}
```

and what I need to do on `View` side ?

Comment: if you display the details of one Course object, you do not need a dropdownlist. The DropdownList is required when you want to insert a new course or update and existing course , in order for user to select a coursecategory.

Comment: @LucianBumb Exactly.. thats what I am trying to do.. Either I want to update the course OR create the new course.. So how can I proceed for that ?

Comment: from your tags I see that you have a Asp.net5 Mvc6 project. In order to get a dropdownlist, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738481/mvc6-dropdownlist-of-countries

Comment: But is there a necessity to create view model(as per provided link), if i have relationship between the models ?

Comment: it is a good practice to send only the data which you need to the view