# The entity type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListGroup' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

New to .Net Core.

Trying to implement a dropdown list similar to:
[MVC6 Dropdownlist of Countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738481/mvc6-dropdownlist-of-countries)

In my model class I have

```
public SelectList SiteList { get; set; }
```

In my controller, I have:

```
var sites = _context.Site.OrderBy(s => s.Name).Select(x => new { Id = x.ID, Value = x.Name });

    var model = new Issue();
    model.SiteList = new SelectList(sites, "Id", "Value");

    return View(model);
```

In my view, I have:

```
<td class="input-item">
<select asp-for="SiteID" asp-items="@Model.SiteList"></select>
</td>
```

When I try to implement a migration, I get the following error:
The entity type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListGroup' requires a primary key to be defined.

I tried ignoring in my Migrations namespace:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>().Ignore(i => i.SiteList);
```

But I'm not entirely sure that I've done this in the right spot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to fix this, simply put

```
[NotMapped]
```

above the SelectList property within the model .cs file:

```
[NotMapped]
public SelectList SiteList { get; set; }
```

This prevents EntityFramework from mapping the list to the model.  Since it's not part of the model database, it doesn't require a primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue before. My problem ended up being that while coding my controller I accidentally generated a DbSet for my view model with the `List<SelectListItem>` on it at the bottom of my `ApplicationDbContext.cs` file. The `[NotMapped]` "fix" is more of a band-aid to the problem than actually solving what's causing the error.

Check around your `ApplicationDbContext.cs` file for a DbSet of the view model that has your `List<SelectListItem>` on it and remove it.

It should look something like this:
`public DbSet<TodoItemViewModel> TodoItemViewModel { get; set; }`

Comment: can you please let us know the alternative solution for it with a simple example?