# Multiple Options in Dynamic Dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

What would be the best approach to have multiple options when using a ViewData for a dropdown list. Something like this [image]

I am using:
 `ViewData["LocationId"] = new SelectList(_context.Location, "LocationId", "Address", employees.LocationId);`
 and it is only showing Address but I need it to :
City
Address
City, State, Postal

In the front end I am calling it like so:
`<select asp-for="LocationId" asp-items="ViewBag.LocationId">`

Can this be done using ViewData and selectList?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change to

```
ViewBag.LocationId = new SelectList(_context.Location, "LocationId", "Address", employees.LocationId);
```

Or if you really want to use ViewData

```
@{
    ...
    var items = ViewData["LocationId"] as IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>;
}

<select asp-for="LocationId" asp-items=@items></select>
```

I recommend reading
[What's the difference between ViewData and ViewBag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705426/whats-the-difference-between-viewdata-and-viewbag)

But this is not really the recommended way to populate your view. You should use ViewModel instead, which allows you to specifically define your view requirements. Here is an example with ViewModel: [MVC6 Dropdownlist of Countries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738481/mvc6-dropdownlist-of-countries)

Comment: The latter looks like the better approach i.e. ViewModel approach. Thank you !